# Angular 7 @Input property binding is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have written a simple angular application with  @input to communicate between components but the value is not being passed.

**app.componenent.html**

```
<app-task [prioirty]="High"></app-task>
```

**`task.component.ts`**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task/services/task.service';
import {AppComponent} from 'src/app/app.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css'],
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {          
  @Input() priortiy: string; 
  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {    
      console.log(this.priority);    
  }  
  ngOnInit() {
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i see you need to make the following changes,

(i) You should enclose the string within quotes as follows

change

**From**

```
<app-task [prioirty]="High"></app-task>
```

**To**

```
<app-task [prioirty]="'High'"></app-task>
```

(ii) Add your console.log inside the ngOnInit not within your constructor as you need to wait until the component gets loaded,

```
ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.priority);    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Please note that **you are using 3 different variables by mistake**! Your variable in TaskComponent is `priortiy` & you are printing `priority` and passing `prioirty` in HTML.

When you use input property binding, you simply need to **pass your value with quotes if it isn't a class property**.
So, your HTML snippet with a ***best practice*** will be -

```
<app-task [priority]="'High'"></app-task>
```

And the following is also valid, where `[]` is now removed & it will consider the value as a string as any html attribute does -

```
<app-task priority="High"></app-task>
```

> In parent to child communication, using appropriate **[component lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)** is ***recommended***. So, in order to get the latest value every time, you'll need to implement **`OnChanges`** interface with the following method -

```
ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.priority);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<app-task prioirty="High"></app-task>
```

when you are using

```
<app-task [prioirty]="High"></app-task>
```

it means High is a variable
but without bracket it means high is a string.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code does not work is that, by using the binding syntax bracket `[]` with value as `High`, It is looking for a property in your component with name `High`.

To fix this, you can either use the following code:

`<app-task priority="High"></app-task>`

or

`<app-task [priority]="'High'"></app-task>`

both of these options will treat the property value as string literal.

Please check the code in the link provided below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-task-input

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a simple typo in the word "priority":

1. <app-task [prioirty]="High">
2. @Input() priortiy: string;

One time it's "prioirty", the second time it's "priortiy". Notice the "i" moving around... Maybe just rename it to "prio" to avoid this easy kind of mistake.

Answer (score -1):

You get the input property after `ngOnChanges()` lifeCycle hook. If you want to check whether you are getting it your child component, add the console in `ngOnInit()` - ngOnInit() runs once after first `ngOnChanges()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.priority);
}
```

Alternatively, log it in ngOnChanges().